# Meteor - accessing the app using public ip

Tags: meteor, localhost

I can access the app using localhost:3000 but I am trying to test from mobile devices locally, without having to deploy it. But I couldn't access the site.

I am allowing incoming request:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I found that my ip address is 128.84.125.239 and so I visit 128.84.125.239:3000 and nothing happens.

Comment: Are your computer and your mobile device on the same wireless lan?

Comment: yes. I also tried accessing with the laptop that is localhosting the app

Comment: do you have `sudo` right on this machine? I can see from the IP that you are at Cornell. Most universities don't give you a whole lot of rights to your machines/networks. That's why I'm asking. Also: what the IP of your mobile device?

Comment: My mobile device have the same IP as my laptop. I don't think there is any restriction because I tried and failed using my home network outside of the school.

Comment: there is something I'm missing: your mobile device and your laptop cannot have the same IP. I'm assuming your laptop is hosting the app? and when you say you tried using your home network: you mean you moved both your (app-hosting) laptop and your mobile device to your home network, or only the mobile device?

Comment: How are you checking your IP? It doesn't really make sense that your mobile and laptop have the same address

Comment: http://cmyip.com/ Is that the correct IP? Both of them are using the home network.

Comment: no, that just shows you your external IP, not the one intern to your network. What does `ifconfig` say? that gives you the IP you are looking for.

Comment: your router will not automatically forward traffic it receives on the external IP to your laptop (for security reasons). So it sounds like you just need to find the internal IP (probably starting with 192.168.) or configure your router NAT.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I only have lo and wlan0 when I type `ifconfig`, so there is no IP starting with 192.168 nor any device eth0, even though my wifi is fine.  This may be getting out of scope but here is what I tried: I found my network controller to be Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230, and so I try using `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` but still I cannot launch eth0.

Comment: you don't need an `eth0`. Just use the IP from your `wlan0`. That's the one you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, it's working. Thanks. Please post to the answer and I will add the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue of using the right IP, or configuring the NAT of the router appropriately. Using a service such as cmyip.com will only provide you with your external IP address. This address can only reach your meteor app if your router is configured accordingly, i.e., the router will forward requests on port 3000 (or whichever port you are running your app on) to your server.

For testing on a mobile device during development you are most likely best off using your internal IP address, assuming your mobile device is on the same network as your app-serving machine.

On Linux you can use `ifconfig` to get your internal IPs. If you are connected via ethernet then you'll be looking for the device `eth0` (in most cases). If you are connected over wifi, then the device you are looking for is typically called `wlan0`.

On Mac OSX you can use `ifconfig` as well, and look for devices called `enX`, where X is a number (often 0, or 2).

Comment: @user2191332 let me know if there are other details you think I should add for fellow answer-seekers.

Comment: So I see two IP's under the active 'en0' device.  `inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255`  Neither of which seem to work for me.  We used to have a different router which never had this issue, but not sure how I'd even go about configuring NAT (or if it's even possible) if that's the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Your service is probably only running locally (on local ports, 127.0.0.0/8), To confirm this, run `netstat -tulpn` to see what services are running and on what ports/interfaces. If you don't see 0.0.0.0:3000 or 128.84.125.239:3000 then you won't be able to get ti it from the IP you are trying and you need to change the bind address of your app to be that IP (or all interaces).

Comment: I see 0.0.0.0:3000 in one of the lines: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3283/node

Comment: Is iptables or anything else being used to manage your firewall rules? Also, what exactly are you seeing when you try to access?

Comment: I have never touched iptable. It just time outs after a minute with "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 128.84.125.239:3000".

Comment: So, this for sure is a web app? Chrome is a web browser so it can only interpret web markup (HTML, CSS, js...)

Comment: Yes. I tried the same thing using AWS EC2 and it works: http://ec2-54-186-36-15.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/  ; the only difference is that I can accept http as supposed to tcp, but I doubt that it makes a difference.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm gonna start trying to throw guesses out there. Did you restart/reload your firewall after you opened up port 3000?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The message from ufw as posted in the question stays the same even after I restart my computer: 3000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere

Comment: I meant you should reload it with 'sudo ufw reload', also you should run 'tcpdump -nn | grep 128.84.125.239.3000' and then try to visit the page in your web browser. This command should show you what you are doing with packets hitting that IP and port.

Comment: I got something like, which doesn't make much sense: 01:58:36.136675 IP 10.0.0.3.50128 > 128.84.125.239.3000: Flags [S], seq 3212940404, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4950331 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0